# Security issues in QEMU

Tags: virtualization

My intention is to add support in QEMU for a new machine/platform. I just started this project, so I can't say more details about it because I don't know them. 
My question is related about the possible security issues that could occur. What are the main security problems about what I should take care?

Comment: This is incredibly broad. All you can really do with QEMU is try to reduce the attack surface area. Enable its native sandbox. Enable chroot. Drop to an unprivileged user. Disable unnecessary features (drivers, etc.).